# Why can we not return a structure to a function?

Tags: c, function, structure

Why can we not return a structure as a return value? I would also like to print it as well? I want to print the variables of the structure returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct distance
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
};

distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2);

distance d3;
int main()
{
    struct distance dist1, dist2,dist3;
    printf("first distance\n");
    scanf("%d",&dist1.feet);
    scanf("%f",&dist1.inch);
    printf("second distance\n");
    scanf("%d",&dist2.feet);
    scanf("%f",&dist2.inch);
    dist3 = add(dist1,dist2);
    printf("sum of distances= %d\'-%.1f\"",dist3.feet,dist3.inch);
    return dist3;
}

 distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2){
    //Adding distances d1 and d2 and storing it in d3
    d3.feet = d2.feet+d1.feet;
    d3.inch = d2.inch+d1.inch;
    if(d3.inch>12){
        d3.inch-=12;
        ++d3.feet;
    }
}
```

The following error message is displayed 
prog.c:7:1: error: unknown type name ‘distance’
 distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2);

Comment: I'm sure you can do this. But you aren't `return`ing anything from `add` for some reason...

Comment: typedef the 'distance' struct.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings.

Comment: The return type of `add` is incorrect. You should have: `struct distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2);`. In the absence of a `typedef`, the type of `struct distance` is `struct distance`.

Comment: yup , i tried ! it didnt

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you can return a structure, but you have to actually return it using the `return` statement:

```
struct distance add(struct distance d1, struct distance d2)
{
  d1.feet += d2.feet;
  d1.inches += d2.inches;
  while(d1.inches > 12)
  {
    ++d1.feet;
    d1.inches -= 12;
  }
  return d1;  /* Return the result. */
}
```

Also no point in creating a `d3` (and certainly not globally!), just use one of the arguments as the new value, and `return` that.

Using a loop to adjust for overflow is better, so I did that too.

Finally, you don't `typedef` the `struct distance` so you can't just say `distance` as the return type, it has to be `struct distance` like the arguments.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, ofcourse if i return dist3 structure, it is showing an error               Compilation error time: 0 memory: 10320 signal:0
prog.c:7:1: error: unknown type name ‘distance’
 distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2)

Comment: Well, maybe you could add the error message/s to the question??

Comment: You seem to have missed the 'struct' before distance.  Maybe you should just typedef 'distance.' at the top and be done with all those 'struct' all over the place..

Comment: @jenny Please read the final paragraph in my answer, where I address that. It's also an error that is not present in my answer code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return it

```
distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2){
    struct distance d3;

    //Adding distances d1 and d2 and storing it in d3
    d3.feet = d2.feet+d1.feet;
    d3.inch = d2.inch+d1.inch;
    if(d3.inch>12){
        d3.inch-=12;
        ++d3.feet;
    }
    return d3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To address this error message:

`prog.c:7:1: error: unknown type name ‘distance’ distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2)`

you need to realize that there's a difference between the types `struct distance` and `distance`.  They are not the same.

Given just:

```
struct distance
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
};
```

This is incorrect, as there is *no* `distance` type:

```
distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2);
```

That code assumes `distance` is a type.  It's not.  The correct type is `struct distance`:

```
struct distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2);
```

You *can* also solve that with a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct distance
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
} distance;
```

Personally, I don't like hiding types that way - I'd rather see something like `struct distance` and know it's a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct distance
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
};

struct distance d1,d2,d3;

struct distance add(struct distance d1, struct distance d2);


int main()
{
    struct distance dist1, dist2,dist3;
    printf("first distance\n");
    scanf("%d",&dist1.feet);
    scanf("%f",&dist1.inch);
    printf("second distance\n");
    scanf("%d",&dist2.feet);
    scanf("%f",&dist2.inch);
    dist3 = add(dist1,dist2);
    printf("sum of distances= %d\'-%.1f\"",dist3.feet,dist3.inch);

}

 struct distance add(struct distance d1,struct distance d2){
    //Adding distances d1 and d2 and storing it in d3
    d3.feet = d2.feet+d1.feet;
    d3.inch = d2.inch+d1.inch;
    while(d3.inch>12){
        d3.inch-=12;
        ++d3.feet;
        return d3;
    }
}
```

Yes got it! here is the final output for the following inputs
inputs:
11
2.3
11
10
and here is the output:
sum of distances= 23'-0.3"

Comment: Defining global variables `d1`, `d2`, `d3` is not a good idea; ignoring `d1` and `d2` is not a good idea; using `d3` in the `add()` function is unnecessary; the `return` in the `add()` function is misplaced (it should be outside the loop).  There may be other issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
} distance;
```

Then get rid of the 'struct' declarations everywhere else...

Note: many thanks to @Lundin for correction:)

Comment: ``typef struct distance
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
}d1,d2,d3;

distance add(distance d1, distance d2);``

Comment: This is wrong, it should be `typedef struct 
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
} distance;`  Or alternatively type out `struct distance` all over the code.